# Select all anchor tags based on href and Change it

Tags: javascript, html, url, google-tag-manager

i have a question regarding changing URL of anchor tags based on HREF.

What i do to select all anchor tags is like this:

```
var anchortags = document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='secureloan.asim.no']");
```

With this i select all anchor tags that refers to secureloan.asim.no

What i want also is to CHANGE the links when user click on it (i want to remove a parameter)

example of URL can be:

> Example URL:
> www.secureloan.asim.no/oasis/index.html#/no/asim?lang=nb-no&product=lev&lanekilde=&campaigncode(etc....).

i want to remove "lanekilde=" from the parameter. im using this code:

```
String(document.location.href).replace("&lanekilde=", "");
```

This gives me right URL but how do i change it for all users on website when they click on it.

Code ive made til now:

```
var anchortags= document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='secureloan.remember.no']");
String(document.location.href).replace("&lanekilde=", "");
```

thank you :)

**PS: NO Jquery please!

PS: im using tag manager if anyone has a idea of different way**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to iterate over the nodeset and change each one in turn:

```
var anchortags = document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='secureloan.asim.no']");
anchortags.forEach(function(tag) {
    tag.href = tag.href.replace('&lanekilde=', '');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this :), i have another question. Ive talked to my collegue and he told me if you do this it will break tracking of Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics aswell as Adwords and SEO. Is that true? he talked about something of redirect changes from 302 to 200 if i do this? and referal changes also

Comment: I'm afraid I can't comment on GTM - I'm not familiar with it; I was answering simply with reference to getting the tags changed. You'll need to ask those who know about GTM.